# Want to translate this Matlab code into OpenCV code

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I want to translate some Matlab code into C++ code with OpenCV. Which functions do I need to use?

For element-wise multiplication, I don't know which function to use.
For example,

```cpp
cv::Mat A; cv::Mat B; cv::Mat C;
C = A + B;
//or
cv::add(A, B, C);
```

This is the MATLAB code:

```matlab
% G and b are constant 
% Rb, CRb and Rb_final are the images

Rb = G(CRb+b);
min3 = min(min(Rb)); % minimum in the Rb image
max3 = max(max(Rb)); % maximum in the Rb image

Rb_final = uint8(255*(Rb-min3)/(max3-min3)); % This function is to scale the image into 0 ~ 255 using maximum and minimum value in the image. And then convert the image into 8-bit unsigned image.
```

This is the OpenCV code I've tried:

```cpp
Rb_final = uint8(255*(Rb-min3)/(max3-min3));
```

I find the max and min by the following code:

```cpp
double max3, min3; 
minMaxLoc(Rb, &min3, &max3); 
Rb = Rb - min3; 
Rb = 255 * Rb; 
Rb = Rb / (max3 - min3);
```

I find like this for all B, G, R channels. But the result is not as good as with `cv::convertScaleAbs(Rb, R, 255, 0);`

Comment: `cv::add()` and `operator+()` are equivalent, see [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga10ac1bfb180e2cfda1701d06c24fdbd6).  The same is true for `cv::multiply` and `*`. See also [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#MatrixExpressions)

Comment: I find the max and min by the following code:

double max3, min3;
minMaxLoc(Rb, &min3, &max3);
Rb = Rb - minb;
Rb = 255 * Rb;
Rb = Rb / (max3 - min3);

like this for all B, G, R channels.

But the result is not as good as the "cv::convertScaleAbs(Rb, R, 255, 0);"

Comment: Sorry! I just edit the question now.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your C++ code is that the image is of type `uint8`, meaning that many operations will overflow (or saturate). For example, multiplying the image by 255 is guaranteed to overflow it. Instead, order the operations so that you don't get overflow:

```cpp
double max3, min3;
minMaxLoc(Rb, &min3, &max3);
Rb = Rb - min3;
Rb = Rb * (255 / (max3 - min3));
```

Alternatively, use `cv::convertScaleAbs`:

```cpp
cv::convertScaleAbs(Rb, Rb, 255 / (max3 - min3), -min3);
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
Rb.convertTo(Rb,CV_32F);
Rb *= C;
Rb += b;
Rb *= G;

double max3, min3;
minMaxLoc(Rb, &min3, &max3);
Rb = 255 * (Rb - min3)/(max3 - min3);

Rb.convertTo(Rb,CV_8U);
```